# i cannot figure out how to read the strings(words) from an input file into a linked list

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};


void insertNode(struct node**, char *);
void printList(struct node*);


int main()
{
  struct node *head = NULL;
  FILE *fptr;
  char file_name[20];
  char str[1000];
  int numOfChar;


  printf("Enter the name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);


  printf("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
  scanf("%d",&numOfChar);


  fptr=fopen(file_name,"r");
    char tokens[100];
  while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), fptr) != NULL)
  {

    while (sscanf(str, "%s", tokens) != EOF)
    {

    }


  }


  fclose(fptr);
  printList(head);


  return 0;
}


void insertNode(struct node** nodeHead, char *data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *last = *nodeHead;
    char *str;


    str= (char *)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str, data);


    new_node->data  = str;
    new_node->next = NULL;


    if (*nodeHead == NULL)
    {
       *nodeHead = new_node;
       return;
    }


    while (last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }


    last->next = new_node;
}
```

My program is supposed to read in each word into a linked list, but I cannot figure out how to get each word/string out of the input file. The input file is an ASCII text file. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

```
void printList(struct node* node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a first approximation, try `fscanf(fptr, "%s", str)` in a loop.

Comment: I tried it in a while loop but it still crashes

Comment: it appears to crash in the insertNode method when i use the fscanf in a while loop. i am not sure why.

Comment: Then you don't have a problem of reading words, you have a problem of inserting them into your list. Try some separation of concerns. Write a program that prints words, one per line. Satisfied? Write a program that inserts three hard-coded words to a list. Satisfied? Combine the two.

Comment: ok. I understand how to print each word out, I just cannot figure out how to insert into a linked list with my program. I am a newbie with c so bear with me.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fptr, "%s", tokens) == 1){ insertNode(&head, tokens); }`

Comment: My program still crashes. thanks for your help.

Comment: Check `fptr` isn't `NULL`

Comment: I checked, it isn't null. My program crashes somewhere in the insertNode method.

Comment: There is a problem in `60`. But otherwise it seems to work.

Comment: what is the problem with line 60? thanks for your help.

Comment: Although I don't advise the scan-to-end algorithm you're using (see [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)), it would seem to me the insertion routine could be [tightened upsubstantially](http://pastebin.com/MQCjW0Pg).

Comment: `malloc(60*sizeof(char))` but `char tokens[100];`

Comment: how do i fix that? sorry i am new to c.

Comment: `malloc(60*sizeof(char))` --> `malloc(strlen(data)+1)`

Comment: whozCraig - my program still crashes when I use tyour insertNode method

Comment: My program still crashes BLUEPIXY. I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Where crash line(sentence)? I think so that the actual code and post code is different.

Comment: ORLY. Does it crash *inside* that routine I posted? Because if it does, State the *exact* line it dies on. Unless `head` incoming isn't properly initialized to NULL when starting with an empty list (which isn't the routine's fault; its the callers) or you flat-out run out of RAM, that routine *will* work.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm *certain* of it at this point.

Comment: it still crashes. I will post my code again as an answer. I am so lost. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried to actually try it, it seems to work without problems.  Where crash line(sentence)? try reboot your PC.

Comment: I do not know the specific crash line. My IDE code::blocks does not tell me. After I enter the input, a dialog box pops up and says assignment2.exe(assignment2 is the name of my project in code::blocks), has stopped working.

Comment: try `printList(head);char c;scanf(" %c", &c);`

Comment: I know it crashes in the insertNode function somewhere because the execution does not return to main. I just cant figure out where.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY did the code i posted in the answer work on your machine?

Comment: By the way, the contents of the input file is present?

Comment: _I do not know the specific crash line._ You can know whether the work properly until where that sprinkle like  `puts("point n passed");`

Comment: The input file is an ASCII text file that contains a paragraph of writing. Do you need me to post it?

Comment: there is no need. Perhaps I think that problem is  another part.

Comment: the while loop in the insertNode function is an infinite loop

Comment: It does not seem  infinite loop.

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36107540/edit) link under your question to add information and improve. Do not post edits as answers, they will be deleted.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/SLiNLc) this  doesn't infinite loop.

Comment: ok thanks @BLUEPIXY. any idea why it is crashing on my machine?

Comment: It's an abnormality in the memory management,
Or
You have a misunderstanding something.

Comment: You need to use a debugger to figure out why it crashes, or at least where (what line). Verify that the code you are running is the code you have posted.

Comment: Or The input file is ginormous.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY could you not mark my other question as a duplicate? it is different.

Comment: It will be canceled if there are people who think the same way.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use very low level character scanning like in the following example - it might be extended to actually accept multiple separator characters, separator repetitions etc.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fptr;
  char buf[100];
  char *p, *s;

  strcpy(buf, "this is just a test");

  fptr=fopen("test.txt","r");
  while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fptr) != NULL)
  {
    printf("LINE: %s\n", buf);
    /* scan characters and print tokens - single space is a separator */
    p = s = buf;
    while(*p!=0) {
      if (*p==' ') {
        *p = 0;
        printf("TOKEN: %s\n", s);
        s = p+1;
      }
      p++;
    }
    printf("TOKEN: %s\n", s);

  }


  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Invocation might look like this:

```
$ cat test.txt
this is test1
this is test2
$ gcc tokens.c && ./a.out
LINE: this is test1

TOKEN: this
TOKEN: is
TOKEN: test1

LINE: this is test2

TOKEN: this
TOKEN: is
TOKEN: test2
```

Comment: How would I use this with my insertNode method? I seem to be having a problem with it crashing when trying to insert a node into the linked list.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's just an example, so probably you should extract the while loop into a function and call insertNode in each printf invocation?

Comment: Look at updated example code. I've changed it to read the contents of `"test.txt"` file and print the tokens in each line

Comment: ok thanks. I am still having trouble when I call my insertNode function. I seem to be getting the correct tokens it is just not adding it to the link list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};


void insertNode(struct node**, char *);
void printList(struct node*);


int main()
{
  struct node *head = NULL;
  FILE *fptr;
  char file_name[20];
  char str[1000];
  int numOfChar;


  printf("Enter the name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);


  printf("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
  scanf("%d",&numOfChar);


  fptr=fopen(file_name,"r");

  while(fscanf(fptr, "%s ", str) != EOF)
  {
      insertNode(&head, str);

  }



  fclose(fptr);
  printList(head);


  return 0;
}


void insertNode(struct node** nodeHead, char *data)
{
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    while (*nodeHead)
        nodeHead = &(*nodeHead)->next;
    *nodeHead = new_node;
}

void printList(struct node* node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, I ran this code against `/usr/share/dict/words`, a common Unix implementation provided word list that contains pretty much every word in the English dictionary (my Mac, for example, has 235886 words in the file. And it executed *without fail*. The only difference between the code I ran and this was (a) I added a test to ensure `fptr` was not NULL, and (b) the test against EOF (I prefer testing `== 1`). Whatever the issue is, I have doubts it is in this code. For certain, failure to open the file would be catastrophic, obviously.

Comment: Prolly should have mentioned, at 200K+ strings and a painter algorithm, it took *forever*, but it did complete none-the-less.