# Trying to read in words from text file and add to linked list, program crashes and i don't know why

Tags: c

My program is supposed to read in each word from a text file and then add it to a linked list, but it crashes after I enter the user input. I have no idea why. I have tried a bunch of different functions and ways but it still crashes. I am lost.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};


void insertNode(struct node**, char *);
void printList(struct node*);


int main()
{
  struct node *head = NULL;
  FILE *fptr;
  char file_name[20];
  char str[1000];
  int numOfChar;


  printf("Enter the name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);


  printf("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
  scanf("%d",&numOfChar);


  fptr=fopen(file_name,"r");

  while(fscanf(fptr, "%s ", str) != EOF)
  {
      insertNode(&head, str);
  }

  fclose(fptr);
  printList(head);


  return 0;
}


void insertNode(struct node** nodeHead, char *data)
{
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    while (*nodeHead)
        nodeHead = &(*nodeHead)->next;
    *nodeHead = new_node;

}

void printList(struct node* node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36107540/971127

Comment: Just realized the while loop in the insertNode function is an infinite loop, but i cannot figure out why.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-codeblocks-debugger-with-c-programm.html

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. It can catch crashes "in action" to help you locate where the crash happens in your code, as well as let you step though code line by line. When stopped at a crash, or stepping through code, you can examine values of all involved variables, and see them change when stepping.

Comment: ^^^ what @JoachimPileborg says.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software and should stop trying.  The #1 debug tool is a debugger, and you have one integrated into your IDE..

Comment: thanks guys. I am new to c and I have stared at this for a while and I cannot figure out the problem. any suggestions on why the insertNode method is in an infinite loop?

Comment: Debugger..........  it's an infinite loop because '*nodeHead' is always true.  Use your debugger to step through and find out how your list came to be circular.

Comment: ok thanks. I ran the debugger and it says there was a segmentation fault at line 57 where the while loop starts.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7cSkbiHUgAKJaA8D).

Comment: @MartinJames Why do you think `*nodeHead` will be always true?

Comment: @B. smith: It is not an infinite loop. Moreover, your `insertNode` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what language you are coding in, if you are not validating your input and your function call returns, you can have no confidence your code is doing anything correctly, and, more importantly, you will have no clue at what point your code begins to fail. This is fundamental. I know you are learning, but start with good habits of validating all input and all function call returns. Your life as a programmer will be made much easier.

Implementing simple validations will tell you where your code is failing and at what point it begins to fail. For example, every time you take input, validate you in fact got what you were expecting. With the `scanf` family of functions, that means, at a minimum, validating that the successful number of conversions took place. If you are unclear what a function returns, or how to gauge success/failure, look at the *man page* for the function. The declaration tells you exactly what *type* of return to expect, and then body of the man page tells you exactly what means success/failure.

```
    printf ("Enter the name of the file: ");
    if (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", file_name) != 1) {   /* validate conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: scanf filename conversion failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
    if (scanf ("%d%*c",&numOfChar) != 1) {      /* validate conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: scanf numOfChar conversion failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fptr = fopen (file_name,"r"))) {      /* validate file open  */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed for '%s'.\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }
```

(side node: the style specification for C, avoids the use of *caMelCase* variable names, all lower-case is preferred. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) )

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: **(1)** always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, **(2)** it can be freed when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you are using the memory you allocate properly and that it is all freed when no longer needed. There are many subtle ways to misuse a new block of memory. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. (it is dead-bang simple to use, just `valgrind ./yourprogram`)

To free your list you will need to free all memory allocated by `strdup` and the memory you allocate directly with `malloc`. With a list, you need to create a second pointer that holds the address of the block to free so you can assign `node = node->next` *before* deleting the node. A short example would be:

```
void freelist (struct node *node)
{
    while (node) {
        struct node *victim = node;
        node = node->next;
        free (victim->data);
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Putting all the pieces together, minimal validation, and proper use of `free` could look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXF = 20, MAXC = 1000 };

struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insertnode (struct node**, char *);
void printlist (struct node*);
void freelist (struct node *node);

int main (void) {

    struct node *head = NULL;
    FILE *fptr;
    char file_name[MAXF];
    char str[MAXC];
    int numOfChar = 0;  /* note: does nothing currently */

    printf ("Enter the name of the file: ");
    if (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", file_name) != 1) {   /* validate conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: scanf filename conversion failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter the number of characters per line: ");
    if (scanf ("%d%*c",&numOfChar) != 1) {      /* validate conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: scanf numOfChar conversion failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fptr = fopen (file_name,"r"))) {      /* validate file open  */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed for '%s'.\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fptr, "%s ", str) != EOF)
        insertnode (&head, str);

    fclose (fptr);
    printlist (head);
    freelist (head);

    return 0;
}

void insertnode (struct node **nodeHead, char *data)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc (sizeof *new_node);
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - new_node.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    while (*nodeHead)
        nodeHead = &(*nodeHead)->next;
    *nodeHead = new_node;
}

void printlist (struct node *node)
{
    while (node) {
        printf(" %s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

void freelist (struct node *node)
{
    while (node) {
        struct node *victim = node;
        node = node->next;
        free (victim->data);
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Second Approach to `insertnode`**

Since you are having problems with `insertnode`, there is another way to iterate over the current nodes (there are actually a few more). Give the following a try:

```
void insertnode (struct node **nodeHead, char *data)
{
    if (!data || !*data) { 
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid 'data' passed to insertnode '%s'.\n",
                data); 
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct node *new_node = malloc (sizeof *new_node);
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - new_node.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (!*nodeHead) {
        *nodeHead = new_node;
    }
    else {
        while ((*nodeHead)->next)
            nodeHead = &((*nodeHead)->next);
        (*nodeHead)->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

**Using a Separate Pointer to Iterate**

```
void insertnode (struct node **nodeHead, char *data)
{
    if (!data || !*data) { 
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid 'data' passed to insertnode '%s'.\n",
                data); 
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct node *new_node = malloc (sizeof *new_node);
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - new_node.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->data = strdup(data);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (!*nodeHead)
        *nodeHead = new_node;
    else {
        struct node *iter = *nodeHead;
        for (; iter->next; iter = iter->next) {}
        iter->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

---

**Answer to Your Second Issue With Printing**

While I like the `fgets` approach to your list, much better than `scanf`, I liked your first list layout better than the current. Your parsing implementation here is a train-wreck for the reasons given in the comment. `strtok` (or `strsep`) are the proper parsing functions for breaking strings into words (or you can do it with pointers -- but it takes much more than you have. Look at the mand page for `strtok`. Here is an example using it to do the word-splitting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list {
    char *string;
    struct list *next;
} LIST;

void freelist (struct list *node);

int main (void) {

    FILE *fp;
    char line[128];
    char file_name[20];
    LIST *current, *head;
    char *p;
    char *delim = " \t\r\n";

    head = current = NULL;
    printf ("Enter the name of the file: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        for (p = strtok (line, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
        {
            LIST *node = malloc (sizeof(LIST));
            if (!(node->string = strdup (p))) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            node->next = NULL;

            if (!head)
                current = head = node;
            else {
                current->next = node;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
        printf("   %s", current->string);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    freelist (head);

    return 0;
}

void freelist (struct list *node)
{
    while (node) {
        struct list *victim = node;
        node = node->next;
        free (victim->string);
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Give it a go -- hopefully no problems -- I'm falling asleep at the keyboard.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I tried to run this on my machine but i get a segmentation fault at the while loop in the insertnode function.

Comment: What 'machine' do you have? Windows, Linux, Mac? You are attempting to read a *plain text* file, right? Add `if (!data || !*data) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid 'data' passed to insertnode '%s'.\n", data); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }` at the top of `insertnode`. I've verified the code on my Linux box. Make sure you are compiling with *warnings enabled*, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`. You remembered the `enum { MAXF = 20, MAXC = 1000 };` at the top, right?

Comment: I am on a windows machine. I am attempting to read a file from notepad, so yes a plain text file. I added the code to the top of insertnode and it still crashes.

Comment: No no no, the file you are trying to read when you get the prompt : `Enter the name of the file:` -- that file must be plain text. Also, you have `\r\n` line endings. Change the first `scanf` *format-specifier* to `"%[^\r\n]%*c"` or just use `"%s"` again.

Comment: Also, if you don't like looking at the debugger, then just add a `printf` to look at `str`. e.g. `while (fscanf....) { printf ("str : %s\n", str); insertnode (&head, str); }`  That way you can look at `str` as it is being read.

Comment: I tried all of that and it still crashes with a segmentation fault at the while loop in the insertnode function. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: What compiler? vs2013? It should make no difference. Doesn't windows use `fscanf_s`. Take a look at [**fscanf_s MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx). I think we are running into a `LOCALE` or `character set` problem. Are you using English, and a standard LOCALE?

Comment: When i use the printf, it displays all of the values of str correctly. Once it goes to the insertnode function it crashes on the while loop.

Comment: I get where you are telling me it is crashing, I'm trying to understand why? I don't use windows, but I've run into obscure issues with the `scanf` (family) *format-specifiers* having issues under VS. (lacking some) However, here those issues are not implicated. Try using `malloc (sizeof (struct node))` instead of `malloc (sizeof *new_node)` in `insertnode`. That really shouldn't matter, but I've seen strange things from VS.

Comment: I am using the Code::Blocks IDE with the GNU GCC compiler. I am not sure which LOCALE or character set i am using.

Comment: I changed the malloc and it still crashes at the same spot.

Comment: Code Blocks has some issues as well, but `gcc` should be rock solid. Are you using this in `mingw`?  The only other thing I can think of is to explicitly set `while (*nodeHead != NULL)`. I can't see that making any difference, but I don't know codeblocks. Also right before the `while` add `printf ("new_node->data : %s\n", new_node->data);` just to make sure `strdup` is working as we think it is since it is allocating memory as well.

Comment: it still crashes for some reason. When i insert the printf before the while it prints out "The" which is the first word in my text file so that is working correctly.

Comment: I'm really reading tealeaves here, but try `nodeHead = &((*nodeHead)->next);` The only thing I can completely speculate is codeblocks isn't handling `&(*nodeHead)->next;`. Which that makes no sense, but an extra set of parens will explicitly set the precedence.

Comment: it still crashes when I change that. One think i noticed is if i put an arbitrary print statement in the while loop it goes into an infinite loop printing that statement.

Comment: Here, If I were writing it, I'd write it slightly different. I'll add an addendum to the answer. See the updated answer.

Comment: I tried the updated insertnode function and it still crashes on the while loop. I have no idea what is going on man.

Comment: I updated again - I didn't like the first update.

Comment: Bad news -- if this last edit doesn't work, you are going to have to look at whatever debugger codeblock has or use `gdb` (don't forget to compile with `-g` to generate the debug symbols if using `gdb`) I don't know what the issue is. Your issues isn't a C issue (this code is 100% standard C). There is something odd going on. I've compiled and run ALL versions of `insertnode` and all work absolutely fine on linux. Take a look at the last amendment.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. i wrote another program that is similar but it doesn't have a segmentation fault, it just goes into an infinite loop when printing the linked list. If i posted it could you try to figure out the problem? I have an assignment due soon and I can't figure this out. I have completely given up on the one i posted in this thread.

Comment: Sure, glad to help, either add the new code to the bottom of this question (but do not delete your original question) or you can open a new one. The print shouldn't be that difficult (or course neither is insert...)

Comment: ok i just posted the new code in another answer

Comment: that worked. Thanks for all of your help man.